# MissingSchema at url

Tags: python, django, http

I'm trying to access a web service in Django using requests.get but I'm having a MissingSchema at api's url,

```
searchin = 'something'
myurl = 'api.webservice.com/search?name='+searchin+'&APIID=abcd'
r = requests.get(myurl)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Long story short, just add http:// or https:// before api.webservice(..)

```
searchin = 'something'
myurl = 'http://api.webservice.com/search?name='+searchin+'&APIID=abcd'
r = requests.get(myurl)
```

Check RFC for URI: https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-3.1
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_Resource_Identifier